# How to match strings using negative lookbehind with multilines?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, negative-lookbehind

I was trying to create [some examples](https://3v4l.org/Y5Jnd) to understand a little better regex assertions with PRCE.

```
//(?<=) - positive lookbehind
$string = "dra Julia \ndr Marcos \ndr Mateus \ndra Ana";
$regex  = "/(?<=dra\s)(\w+)/im";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Runs fine returning "**Julia**" and "**Ana**"
But the negative version:

```
$regex  = "/(?<!^dra\s)\b\w+\b$/im";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Returns empty :(
I was expecting "**Marcos**" and "**Mateus**" like using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XeKKs9/1).

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Why you need the negative Version to expect "Marcos" and "Mateus"? try this: "/(?<=dr\s)(\w+)/i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space after the names. Note that `\s` also matches a newline and `\h` matches horizontal whitespace char.

You could update your pattern to:

```
(?<!^dra\h)\b\w+\b\h*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wv230N/1)

To get the name without the trailing space you might use [a lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/9e7RLS/1) or a [capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/MMKHwR/1)